which gripper collision geometry to use in URDF
I am building a robot arm and right now I am adjusting my URDF. The gripper has a quite complex geometry. Does it make sense to use the original STL (or STEP) file (that i normally would only use for visuals to keep computation low) as geometry in this case? I also want to plan gripping etc. in the simulation. Will the computation time be increased significantly through that?
I can not really approximate the gripper through simple geometries.
Thanks a lot in advance.

You can check out the git repository for the Robotiq gripper ROS implementation here or ROS2 here for reference. I've only ever encountered the gripper being defined as an STL file and the computation time doesn't seem affected much by the visual definition.
